# Setup GitFlow in VSTS - Best practices?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, git-flow

Is there any recommendation how to set up GitFlow with Visual Studio TeamServices?

We come from BitBucket and there it's just a simple init. But in VSTS we cannot find any scaffolding. It seems to be we have to set up a lot of manual settings, right? So how to setup usergroups, policies... for a recommended usage with GitFlow in VSTS?

Comment: Can you tell more about the specifics on what you'd expect in terms of policy and security? The flow itself isn't hard to setup and you'd start doing that locally. Plus, you can create one CI build which has a refs/heads/* branch filter so it just triggers on everything... GitFlow doesn't require Pull Requests and Code Reviews etc... it just documents the flow of commits.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard one-click button to setup branches and policies on VSTS to support GitFlow or another type of flow framework for Git (like GitHubFlow etc).

The setup isn't too hard, but can involve many manual steps. You'd be able to turn this into an init script using the REST API to have it generate the builds (with wildcards on the branch filters), set the branch policies and lock the branches with the right security.

At the same time, there is not really a default setup for GitFlow if there is enough trust in the team... The security group for just about everything in that case would just be "default team".

There is a Visual Studio plugin by the way, which will help you setup the branch structure and the merge flow between branches.

- https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f5ae0a1d-005f-4a09-a19c-3f46ff30400a